# Extjs pass Data in new window

Tags: extjs

my setup: i have a **file1** which is a Form Panel defined. I have another **file2** which creates the form panel from the **file1** and open it in a new Window.

My question now is it possible to transfer datas to the new opened window? In my case, i have a grid panel in **file1**. Now when i select one of the rows from the grid, i will transfer these data to the new window when i click a button. In my new window the Form will shown the datas from the grid panel for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a grid and want to open one record in a window, you would do sth like:

```
itemdblclick:function(grid,record,item) {
    Ext.create('MyWindow',{
        record:record // here, you set window.record = clicked record
    });
}
```

and

```
Ext.define('MyWindow',{
    items:[{
        xtype:'form',
        items:[{
            ...
        }]
    }],
    listeners:{
        beforerender:function(window) {
            // here, you load window.record into the form!
            if(window.record) window.down('form').loadRecord(window.record);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know, I copied it directly from my ext project... :D